# How to disable JavaScript in chrome using Chrome driver (Python and Selenium)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

My goal is to disable JavaScript loading of a page to get the data that appears before loading and compare it with the data after loading.

Im using:

- **Selenium** version 3.141.0
- **Python** 3.6.8
- **Chromedriver** 83.0.4103.39
- **macOS Catalina** 10.15.5

I have tried to use this, but it does not work in my case:

```
options.add_experimental_option(
"prefs", {'profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript': 2})
```

and this:

```
prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values': {'cookies': 2, 'images': 2, 'javascript': 2, 
                        'plugins': 2, 'popups': 2, 'geolocation': 2, 
                        'notifications': 2, 'auto_select_certificate': 2, 'fullscreen': 2, 
                        'mouselock': 2, 'mixed_script': 2, 'media_stream': 2, 
                        'media_stream_mic': 2, 'media_stream_camera': 2, 'protocol_handlers': 2, 
                        'ppapi_broker': 2, 'automatic_downloads': 2, 'midi_sysex': 2, 
                        'push_messaging': 2, 'ssl_cert_decisions': 2, 'metro_switch_to_desktop': 2, 
                        'protected_media_identifier': 2, 'app_banner': 2, 'site_engagement': 2, 
                        'durable_storage': 2}}
```

I have been looking for more ways to get it but without success, I hope someone knows another solution that works